# What does "Lifesaver" mean on the Play of the Game?

Tags: terminology, overwatch

I've noticed that sometimes, a highlight video or the Play of the Game has the text "Lifesaver" appended during the intro, usually below the hero's waist. However, I haven't noticed any differences from the usual "get a significant multikill or capture" videos.

What causes "Lifesaver" to appear, and are there any other similar modifiers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you see a Lifesaver footnote in the PoTG screen, this is intended to feature situations where one player is able to save another player (or players) from imminent death. For example: If Reinhardt has an enemy pinned, and that enemy's teammate stuns or kills Reinhardt, the teammate would be awarded a large amount of "Lifesaver" score. If Mercy has 5 of her teammates downed, and casts her ultimate, the same situation would apply and Mercy would be awarded a large amount of "Lifesaver" score as well.

From the [Overwatch wiki](http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Play_of_the_Game):

> The player who **has the highest score** in any one of these four
>   categories at the end of the match will receive the Play of the Game.
>   If the winning Play of the Game category is Lifesaver, Sharpshooter,
>   or Shutdown then the category name will be called out during the
>   highlight intro. If the winning category is High Score, however, no
>   callout will be provided.